# Getting error in Fetching Data from DataTable's Select method using "Like" operator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable

I am using following code

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in letGrdSignList)
                {
                    //Check if added function in definition is modified, if yes then don't add it in signature list
                    DataRow[] dLetRow = dtLet.Select("Definition" + "Like"" + "'" +
                        "%"+ kvp.Value + "%" + "'");
                   //kvp.value contains  "local:try2values($arg1 as xs:decimal,$arg2 as xs:float*)"     
                   //Above line results in error

                   if (dLetRow.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //Check if signature already exists
                        if (!strList.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                            strList.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }
                    //else
                    //    //Remove from list if signature is not present in any defination column
                    //    letGrdSignList.Remove(sLetSignature);ss
                }


I am getting following error
{System.Data.EvaluateException: Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%local:try2values($arg1 as xs:decimal,$arg2 as xs:float*)%' is invalid.
   at System.Data.LikeNode.AnalyzePattern(String pat)
   at System.Data.LikeNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
   at System.Data.Select.AcceptRecord(Int32 record)
   at System.Data.Select.GetLinearFilteredRows(Range range)
   at System.Data.Select.SelectRows()
   at System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)
   at WPFApp.QueryGenerator.GetSignatureList()
```

screenshot of code

from MSDN if found this 
Wildcard Characters

Both the * and % can be used interchangeably for wildcard characters in a LIKE comparison. If the string in a LIKE clause contains a * or %, those characters should be enclosed in brackets ([]). If a bracket is in the clause, each bracket character should be enclosed in brackets (for example [[] or []]). A wildcard is allowed at the start and end of a pattern, or at the end of a pattern, or at the start of a pattern. For example:

"ItemName LIKE '*product*'"

"ItemName LIKE '*product'"

"ItemName LIKE 'product*'"

Wildcard characters are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape "%" when using Like operator

```
//Check if added function in definition is modified, if yes then don't add it in signature list
    DataRow[] dLetRow = dtLet.
       Select("Definition Like '[%]%" + kvp.Value + "[%]%'");
```

Comment: hey thanks man , I also did the similar thing and code is running well , I just want to make sure whether this approach is right or not

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the line with this one

```
 DataRow[] dLetRow = dtLet.Select("Definition" + "Like"" + "'" +
                        "%"+ kvp.Value.replace("*","[*]") + "%" + "'");
```

this fixed up the bug , but i m not sure whether the approach is right or not